# Sharing a WAV Audio to Whatsapp on Android shortens it

Tags: android, whatsapp

My Android app generates a WAV and shares it to Whatsapp. This function is broken since Android 6.0. Audio sharing still works, however only around half on the file is playable. The rest is missing.

I tested other WAV files and they also get shortened. Sharing appears to work for MP3 files.

How can I work around this?